# How do I embed a SVG created by React.createElement?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

### Background

I am trying to embed an SVG into an image tag within React like so:

e.g.

```js
import Delete from '@carbon/icons-react/es/delete/16'

...

render() {
   return <img src={Delete} alt="delete" />
}
```

### Issue

However, the `Delete` element is an object and not an SVG element when within the image's src attribute and thus, is not correctly displayed.

```js
<img src="[object Object]" alt="delete">
```

How do I properly embed this SVG within an image tag?

### Delete.js

⚠️ Note: This is a component taken from [@carbon/icons-react](https://github.com/carbon-design-system/carbon-elements/tree/master/packages/icons-react).

```js
import { getAttributes } from '@carbon/icon-helpers';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import React from 'react';

function _typeof(obj) { if (typeof Symbol === "function" && typeof Symbol.iterator === "symbol") { _typeof = function _typeof(obj) { return typeof obj; }; } else { _typeof = function _typeof(obj) { return obj && typeof Symbol === "function" && obj.constructor === Symbol && obj !== Symbol.prototype ? "symbol" : typeof obj; }; } return _typeof(obj); }

function _objectSpread(target) { for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) { var source = arguments[i] != null ? arguments[i] : {}; var ownKeys = Object.keys(source); if (typeof Object.getOwnPropertySymbols === 'function') { ownKeys = ownKeys.concat(Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(source).filter(function (sym) { return Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(source, sym).enumerable; })); } ownKeys.forEach(function (key) { _defineProperty(target, key, source[key]); }); } return target; }

function _defineProperty(obj, key, value) { if (key in obj) { Object.defineProperty(obj, key, { value: value, enumerable: true, configurable: true, writable: true }); } else { obj[key] = value; } return obj; }

function _objectWithoutProperties(source, excluded) { if (source == null) return {}; var target = _objectWithoutPropertiesLoose(source, excluded); var key, i; if (Object.getOwnPropertySymbols) { var sourceSymbolKeys = Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(source); for (i = 0; i < sourceSymbolKeys.length; i++) { key = sourceSymbolKeys[i]; if (excluded.indexOf(key) >= 0) continue; if (!Object.prototype.propertyIsEnumerable.call(source, key)) continue; target[key] = source[key]; } } return target; }

function _objectWithoutPropertiesLoose(source, excluded) { if (source == null) return {}; var target = {}; var sourceKeys = Object.keys(source); var key, i; for (i = 0; i < sourceKeys.length; i++) { key = sourceKeys[i]; if (excluded.indexOf(key) >= 0) continue; target[key] = source[key]; } return target; }
var defaultStyle = {
  "willChange": "transform"
};
var Delete16 = React.forwardRef(function (_ref, ref) {
  var className = _ref.className,
      children = _ref.children,
      style = _ref.style,
      tabIndex = _ref.tabIndex,
      rest = _objectWithoutProperties(_ref, ["className", "children", "style", "tabIndex"]);

  var _getAttributes = getAttributes(_objectSpread({}, rest, {
    tabindex: tabIndex
  })),
      tabindex = _getAttributes.tabindex,
      props = _objectWithoutProperties(_getAttributes, ["tabindex"]);

  if (className) {
    props.className = className;
  }

  if (tabindex !== undefined && tabindex !== null) {
    props.tabIndex = tabindex;
  }

  if (_typeof(style) === 'object') {
    props.style = _objectSpread({}, defaultStyle, style);
  } else {
    props.style = defaultStyle;
  }

  if (ref) {
    props.ref = ref;
  }

  return React.createElement('svg', props, children, React.createElement('path', {
    d: 'M6 6h1v6H6zm3 0h1v6H9z'
  }), React.createElement('path', {
    d: 'M2 3v1h1v10c0 .6.4 1 1 1h8c.6 0 1-.4 1-1V4h1V3H2zm2 11V4h8v10H4zM6 1h4v1H6z'
  }));
});
Delete16.displayName = 'Delete16';
Delete16.propTypes = {
  'aria-hidden': PropTypes.bool,
  'aria-label': PropTypes.string,
  'aria-labelledby': PropTypes.string,
  className: PropTypes.string,
  children: PropTypes.node,
  height: PropTypes.number,
  preserveAspectRatio: PropTypes.string,
  tabIndex: PropTypes.string,
  viewBox: PropTypes.string,
  width: PropTypes.number,
  xmlns: PropTypes.string
};
Delete16.defaultProps = {
  width: 16,
  height: 16,
  viewBox: '0 0 16 16',
  xmlns: 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg',
  preserveAspectRatio: 'xMidYMid meet'
};

export default Delete16;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to embed an SVG element, you need to import it first

```
    import DeleteIcon from '@carbon/icons-react/es/delete/icon.svg'
```

And then do as you do:

```
    render() {
       return <img src={DeleteIcon} alt="delete" />
    }
```

But looks like in your case you just need to use it as component:

```
    import DeleteIcon from '@carbon/icons-react/es/delete/16'

    render() {
        return <DeleteIcon />
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however, Carbon does not provide a file such as `icon.svg`, it uses `React.createElement()` as seen in my posted question above.

Comment: Yeah, I could use it as a component, but there is a use case where I need it to be embedded within an image tag.

Comment: @NicholasAdamou I've updated the response, is it your case?

Comment: When I fire a `onClick` event on the svg, `event.target` sometimes returns the SVG element and other times returns the `path` element nested within the svg tag. I need it to only return the svg element

Comment: There is no way to embed it as you want to. You only can go to sources, copy svg and path, create svg icon file and then embed.

Comment: To not to get nested elements as `event.target` you need to `stopPropagation()`, but you'll have to change the library, what is not good.
The other way is to find parent `svg` if you get the `path`.